# The update function cannot change the data, when I click the button the data does not change

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Edit Condemning Details')

@section('contents')

<div class="container mt-4">
    <hr>

    <form action="{{ route('oil.update', $oil) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        
        <div class="row">
        @foreach ($columns as $column)
            <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                <label for="{{ $column }}" class="form-label">{{ $column }}</label>
                <input type="text" name="{{ $column }}" value="{{ $oil->{$column} }}" class="form-control">
            </div>
                @if ($loop->iteration % 5 == 0)
                </div><div class="row">
                @endif
        @endforeach
        </div>

    
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        {{-- <a href="{{ route('oil.index') }}" class="btn btn-secondary">Back to Index</a> --}}
    </form>
    
    
</div>
@endsection
```

Here I use looping because the data in my table is quite a lot, and to display the data it has been successful

Controller

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $oil = Oil::findOrFail($id);
        $columns = Schema::getColumnListing('condem');
        
        $columns = array_diff($columns, ['condemID', 'modelID']);
        
        return view('oil.edit', compact('oil', 'columns'));
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'Vk 40 min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Vk 40 max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Vk 40 border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Vk 40 per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Vk 40 ket' => 'required|string',
            'Vk 100 min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Vk 100 max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Vk 100 border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Vk 100 per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Vk 100 ket' => 'required|string',
            'Oxi min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Oxi max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Oxi border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Oxi per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Oxi ket' => 'required|string',
            'P min' => 'required|numeric',
            'P max' => 'required|numeric',
            'P border' => 'required|numeric',
            'P per' => 'required|numeric',
            'P ket' => 'required|string',
            'Wt min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Wt max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Wt border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Wt per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Wt ket' => 'required|string',
            'Zn min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Zn max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Zn border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Zn per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Zn ket' => 'required|string',
            'Soot min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Soot max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Soot border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Soot per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Soot ket' => 'required|string',
            'Nit min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Nit max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Nit border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Nit per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Nit ket' => 'required|string',
            'TAN min' => 'required|numeric',
            'TAN max' => 'required|numeric',
            'TAN border' => 'required|numeric',
            'TAN per' => 'required|numeric',
            'TAN ket' => 'required|string',
            'Ca min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Ca max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Ca border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Ca per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Ca ket' => 'required|string',
            'Fu min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Fu max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Fu border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Fu per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Fu ket' => 'required|string',
            'TBN min' => 'required|numeric',
            'TBN max' => 'required|numeric',
            'TBN border' => 'required|numeric',
            'TBN per' => 'required|numeric',
            'TBN ket' => 'required|string',
            'Ag min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Ag max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Ag border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Ag per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Ag ket' => 'required|string',
            'Sn min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Sn max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Sn border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Sn per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Sn ket' => 'required|string',
            'Pb min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Pb max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Pb border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Pb per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Pb ket' => 'required|string',
            'Fe min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Fe max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Fe border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Fe per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Fe ket' => 'required|string',
            'Cu min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Cu max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Cu border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Cu per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Cu ket' => 'required|string',
            'Cr min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Cr max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Cr border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Cr per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Cr ket' => 'required|string',
            'Al min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Al max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Al border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Al per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Al ket' => 'required|string',
            'Si min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Si max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Si border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Si per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Si ket' => 'required|string',
            'Na min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Na max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Na border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Na per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Na ket' => 'required|string',
            'PI min' => 'required|numeric',
            'PI max' => 'required|numeric',
            'PI border' => 'required|numeric',
            'PI per' => 'required|numeric',
            'PI ket' => 'required|string',
            'Pl min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Pl max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Pl border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Pl per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Pl ket' => 'required|string',
            'TI min' => 'required|numeric',
            'TI max' => 'required|numeric',
            'TI border' => 'required|numeric',
            'TI per' => 'required|numeric',
            'TI ket' => 'required|string',
            'Sulf min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Sulf max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Sulf border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Sulf per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Sulf ket' => 'required|string',
            'Mg min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Mg max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Mg border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Mg per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Mg ket' => 'required|string',
            'Mo min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Mo max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Mo border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Mo per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Mo ket' => 'required|string',
            'NAS 1638 min' => 'required|numeric',
            'NAS 1638 max' => 'required|numeric',
            'NAS 1638 border' => 'required|numeric',
            'NAS 1638 per' => 'required|numeric',
            'NAS 1638 ket' => 'required|string',
            'V min' => 'required|numeric',
            'V max' => 'required|numeric',
            'V border' => 'required|numeric',
            'V per' => 'required|numeric',
            'V ket' => 'required|string',
            'FP COC min' => 'required|numeric',
            'FP COC max' => 'required|numeric',
            'FP COC border' => 'required|numeric',
            'FP COC per' => 'required|numeric',
            'FP COC ket' => 'required|string',
            'Wt D 95 min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Wt D 95 max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Wt D 95 border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Wt D 95 per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Wt D 95 ket' => 'required|string',
            'Wt KF min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Wt KF max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Wt KF border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Wt KF per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Wt KF ket' => 'required|string',
            'Gly min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Gly max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Gly border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Gly per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Gly ket' => 'required|string',
            'TBN_D4739 min' => 'required|numeric',
            'TBN_D4739 max' => 'required|numeric',
            'TBN_D4739 border' => 'required|numeric',
            'TBN_D4739 per' => 'required|numeric',
            'TBN_D4739 ket' => 'required|string',
            'PP min' => 'required|numeric',
            'PP max' => 'required|numeric',
            'PP border' => 'required|numeric',
            'PP per' => 'required|numeric',
            'PP ket' => 'required|string',
            'Ni min' => 'required|numeric',
            'Ni max' => 'required|numeric',
            'Ni border' => 'required|numeric',
            'Ni per' => 'required|numeric',
            'Ni ket' => 'required|string',
            'B min' => 'required|numeric',
            'B max' => 'required|numeric',
            'B border' => 'required|numeric',
            'B per' => 'required|numeric',
            'B ket' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    
        $oil = Oil::findOrFail($request->id);
        $oil->update($validatedData);

        return redirect()->route('oil.show')->with('success', 'Oil details updated successfully');
    }
```

I created the controller above to make it easier to validate data

route

```
Route::controller(OilController::class)->prefix('oil')->group(function () {
        Route::get('', 'index')->name('oil');
        Route::get('show/{id}', 'show')->name('oil.show');
        Route::get('/{id}/edit', [OilController::class, 'edit'])->name('oil.edit');
        Route::put('/oil/{id}', [OilController::class, 'update'])->name('oil.update');
        Route::delete('destroy/{id}', 'destroy')->name('oil.destroy');
    });
```

Here's the route I used.

I want to edit the data, and I have tried to create it but the data does not change, when I press the update button it only returns to the initial page, which should return to the index page, and the data will change. What should I change for the code?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `the data does not change when I want to make data changes`

Comment: I want to edit the data, but there is no change, that's what I mean, sorry if my language english is not right.

Comment: Is your issue resolved? @arthurr

Comment: I bet that you got some validation errors but you haven't shown them in your blade. That's why you don't see anything except redirection. @arthurr

Comment: @FarhanIbnWahid not yet bro :), i still find how to resolve the issue

Comment: @arthurr did you print validation errors in your blade yet? you should, then you would see the errors

Comment: @FarhanIbnWahid already, but it doesn't show anything

Comment: add in your question what you added for showing errors above the form in blade @arthurr

Answer (score 1):

it's always easier to figure out what's wrong by debugging, not just trying to guess.

1. add `{{ route('oil.update', $oil) }}` somewhere to form (or check it in DevTools in your brouser) to ensure that URL is correct
2. add `dd('smth')` as the first string in your update method to check if method is reached at all;
3. add `dd($validatedData)` after validation to check if your data is validated
4. add `dd('smth')` vefor returning from update (after saving model).

at least you will decrease the amont of possible problems.

PS but I bet smth's wrong in you update route (otherwise you would've got some error instead of being just redirected).